# Best practice to get summary/filters from a large SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

In our system, a user can be of 2 types

1. Client
2. Affiliate client

The client can have one listing and Affiliate clients can have multiple listings.
So we get calls against listings and we store them in a table called call logs table.

Now this table has ~5 million records and this table grows every minute. A call log belongs to a listing and a user(client/affiliate). So a call log can have (a client id and a listing id) OR
(an affiliate client id and listing id).

We show filters on the call logs page an admin portal to filters the call logs. Admin can filter the call logs by Clients, Affiliates Client, and Listings.

This is how I get clients, affiliates, and listings from the call logs table to make filters.

`` select * from `call_logs` order by `call_logs`.`id` asc limit 500 offset 0 ``

So after getting the 500 call logs, I extract

1. Users with type client and store them in a variable named client filter array.
2. Users with type affiliate client and store in a variable called affiliate filter array.
3. Unique listings and store in a listings filter array.

After looping through the whole table of call_logs, because I chunk up the table to 500 rows per loop, I displayed those filters on the admin portal page.

**Issue/Problem:**
Because the table is large, so separation of users on the base of type(Client and affiliate client) and listing take a long time, so the admin has to wait for page loading.
I have also tried to load those filters after the page is successfully loaded via ajax, but most of the time its takes too long.

I can't use groups by user types like user_id, affiliate_client_id, or listing_id. Because if a group by affiliate_client_id, so the affiliate can have multiple listings with different calls, so it will pick on one call, the same thing for listing.

Comment: Is that query running slow? What does the execution plan tell you about it? Having an intermediate table with calculated results will put you in tons of trouble: who guarantees that this table is up-to-date? And won't that generate a lot of data that is never queried (if users are never logging in)?

Comment: @NicoHaase So what practice should I follow, if an intermediate table will cause an issue. We will not generate data when a user will do log in, we will be updating the intermediate table via cron job running after every 30 minutes or 1 hour.

Comment: Why not check the execution plan of that query first if you assume that there is any problem - just to clarfiy: **is** there any current problem, or do you fear that a problem could arise in the future?

Comment: I think, I have to make a video and paste the google drive link here, so you can understand better my question.

Comment: Please just add the execution plan of such a query. There's no need to put such information into a video

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited my whole question to another case scenario, I hope you will understand it easily now,

Answer (score 0):

you need an index on user_id and call_fee columns and this query calculate the call fee for all the users in one query:

```
SELECT `user_id`,sum(`call_fee`) 
FROM `call_logs` 
GROUP BY `user_id`;
```

Comment: I am already doing group by.  The thing is on the admin panel page, it has to calculate the call fee for all users. So calculation takes time, so the dashboard page is loading too long to respond.

Comment: Do you have index ? As I mentioned in my answer . But seems like yo are not showing us the whole thing, provide more detail information including exécration plan

Comment: Not yet, But if I add an index, for now, it will help, but in the future table will grow, we will be facing the same issue.

Comment: What you mean it won't help in future, it will be useful  no matter the size of your table

Comment: Yeah I know indexing boost the search operation, but suppose in the future we will be having the size of table ~20Millions, so the query will take long right? so until the calculation is done for all users, on the admin dashboard page, the admin has to wait until the page loads(because query is in-progress).

Comment: I have edited my whole question to another case scenario, I hope you will understand it easily now,